# Direct limit with non-injective maps

Tags: abstract-algebra, category-theory

Suppose I take a direct limit in the category of groups, or the category of R-modules, or similar. Let $I$ denote the index set, $A_i$ the objects and $f_{ij}: A_i \to A_j$ the structure maps of the direct system. The colimit over this direct system can then be computed via a coequalizer (as e.g. explained in http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direct_limit). Now in general no requirements are made with respect to the structure maps $f_{ij}$, in particular it is not required that these maps are injective. I was wondering whether there are some conditions on the direct system to ensure that the direct limit object is isomorphic to a direct limit object which is computed using a direct system with only injective structure maps.

Suppose we have a direct system of the shape (taking $I = \mathbb N$)
$$
A_0 \to A_1 \to A_2 \to \ldots
$$
Then we can pass to the following direct system: As objects we take $A'_i = A_i/\ker(f_{i,i+1})$. As structure maps we use the following maps, given by composing the canonical maps:
$$
f'_{i,i+1} \colon A'_i = A_i/\ker(f_{i,i+1}) \to A_{i+1} \to A_{i+1}/\ker(f_{i+1,i+2}) = A'_{i+1}
$$
Now if I am not mistaken, we have that $\operatorname{colim}_i A_i \cong \operatorname{colim}_i A'_i$. Of course the new structure maps need not be injective, since we pass to a quotient of $A_{i+1}$. However we can iterate this construction. We would need some "uniform" ascending chain condition to actually obtain a direct system with injective maps after finitely many iterations.

Now these are just some vague ideas. I hope someone can give me a hint or references where this question is addressed.

Comment: Well, you can always look at the boring direct system $A \to A \to A \to A \to \cdots$ where $A$ is the direct limit of your original direct system.

Comment: You are right. Of course I want to be in the interesting situation where the colimit is assembled from small pieces, e.g. finite, or finitely generated, etc. And then the iteration process should preserve this smallness property.

Comment: $A_i' \cong \mathrm{im}f_{i,i+1}$